# Uploading another image from an API if the image is missing?

Tags: reactjs, image, mapping, jsx, use-effect

So I have an API in which the last part is missing two things: price and image.

As you can see I've putted a condition for the price (if the price is missing, put it at 3.99). I tried to do the same for the image (if the image is missing, show me the image I've uploaded, in this case Granulator1.PNEG) but it's not showing me any of the images.

Can somebody tell if I've written the condition well?

CodeSandbox link:
[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/learning-react-5vj5g?file=/src/PropTypesLearning.js)

And here is the code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import defaultImage from "./Granulator1.PNG";

const url = "https://course-api.com/react-prop-types-example";

export default function PropTypesLearning() {
const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);

async function getData() {
const resp = await fetch(url);
const data = await resp.json();
setInfo(data);
}

useEffect(() => {
getData();
}, []);

return (
<div>
  {info.map((prices) => {
    const { id, name, price, image } = prices;
    const url = image && image.url;
    return (
      <div key={id}>
        {name} <br />
        {price || 3.99}
        <image src={url || defaultImage} alt="" />
      </div>
    );
  })}
 </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Just change`<image />` to `<img />`

Comment: @fullstack Such a simple mistake. Thank you.